# Java NullPointerException in MimeHeaders.clear and MimeHeaders.getValue in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, nullpointerexception

Recently our devops noticed that our production servers are getting many java.lang.NullPointerException errors:

1. The issue is outside the scope of our code so we do not know which endpoint is the culprit and we do not have a direction to look at
2. The exceptions always arrive in triplets (see below)
3. The system runs on many servers with a lot of throughput
4. The system is currently running an old version of tomcat (tomcat6)

The errors:

```
 Jan 26, 2022 5:53:05 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor process
        SEVERE: Error processing request
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.clear(MimeHeaders.java:152)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.reset(Response.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.reset(Response.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

  Jan 26, 2022 5:53:05 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor process
        SEVERE: Error finishing response
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getValue(MimeHeaders.java:324)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.prepareResponse(Http11Processor.java:1617)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:958)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:184)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:403)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:903)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Jan 26, 2022 5:53:05 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler process
        SEVERE: Error reading request, ignored
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.clear(MimeHeaders.java:152)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.recycle(Response.java:552)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.nextRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:925)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What we tried:

1. We ran traffic to an upgraded server (tomcat 9) - the issue persists
2. Rolling back version (assuming it is a new issue) - it turns out that the issue is old
3. Reproducing in development environment with standard scenarios - does not reproduce

Answer (score 0):

According to https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47655#c9
java.lang.NullPointerException in MimeHeaders can only be a result of concurrent calls to response.setHeader and/or response.addHeader.
From there it was easy to find the concurrent calls on the same response instance in our code.